# Running through multiple command line parameters

Tags: ruby

This is a school assignment I've been working on this for a while now and it only works with 1 parameter given.  I've tried a lot of different scenarios using ARGV and think I'm just missing something.

This program is supposed to run through as many directories as given in the command line.  It should default to the current working directory if no parameters are given.

I'll provide the code that works for one parameter.  Again, I just need to be able to have this take in multiple parameters.

```
directory = ARGV[0] || Dir.pwd
searchstring = Regexp.new "(\\.[^.]+)$"


extensions = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = {size: 0, count: 0}}

if File.exists? File.expand_path(directory)
  Dir["#{File.expand_path(directory)}/*/**"].each.map do |f|
    if File.basename(f) =~ searchstring
      extensions[File.extname(f)][:size] += File.stat(f).size
      extensions[File.extname(f)][:count] += 1
      end
    end
else
  puts "This directory does not exist"
end
puts (extensions.map{ |k,v| "Extension: #{k} => #{v}"}.sort)
```

EDIT: I also just noticed that it's only going through subdirectories.  I know I can make it go through just the given directory by getting rid of the extra /** earlier when I'm looping through my filenames.  How do I make it look at both the directory given and all of its subdirectories?

I also think I've pretty much answered my own question with what I originally answered with cycling through mulitple arguments.  However, I still don't know how to go through all subdirectories.  I'll post my latest code so everyone can see the difference.

```
    ARGV[0]=Dir.pwd if ARGV.length < 1

for i in 0 ... ARGV.length


directory=ARGV[i]
searchstring = Regexp.new "(\\.[^.]+)$"

extensions = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = {size: 0, count: 0}}

if File.exists? File.expand_path(directory)
  Dir["#{File.expand_path(directory)}/*"].each.map do |f|
    if File.basename(f) =~ searchstring
      extensions[File.extname(f)][:size] += File.stat(f).size
      extensions[File.extname(f)][:count] += 1
      end
    end
else
  puts "This directory does not exist"
end
puts "#{directory}"
puts (extensions.map{ |k,v| "Extension: #{k} => #{v}"}.sort)
end
```

Comment: Fixed a the multiple arguments issue on my own.  Still need help though.

Comment: you can use `/**/*` e.g. `Dir["#{File.expand_path(directory)}/**/*"]` to look recursively, but it will look at everything below the directory not just the top-level subdirectories.

Comment: I tried that, I need it to look at the current directory and all subdirectories though.

Comment: I think I'm good.  I'm just using a wildcard when entering the parameter